# Can I include a table creation date in a table name in a big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to run a table operation repeatedly.
Can I include a table creation date in a table name in a big query?

Comment: You would normally do this using partitions or shards.  So I guess the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to verify the [Table naming conventions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#table_naming)in BigQuery:

- Contain up to 1,024 characters
- Contain letters (upper or lower case), numbers, and underscores